# Does using Firestore require the firebase-firestore.js file?

Tags: firebase, dependencies, google-cloud-firestore

I am using Firebase in my project, including Firestore.

The docs say when setting up Firestore to include firebase-firestore.js in addition to the normal firebase.js file.

Is this required? I included it, but am also looking to reduce dependencies whenever possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's required.  firebase.js contains common code for all Firebase products you might use.